# Javascript - Get custom attribute of each selectpicker selected value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I receive an array of objects which are the selected options of a bootstrap selectpicker using `var roles = $("#adminUserRoles").find("option:selected");`. I would like to loop over each item in roles and get a custom attribute `data-value` however no matter what I try I can't seem to get each item as an object, I rather get it as a chunk of html.

Edit: I iterate the set using

```
roles.each(function(item, index){
                console.log(item.attr('data-value');
                console.log(roles[index].attr('data-value')
            });
```

and receive `Uncaught TypeError: item.attr is not a function`

HTML:

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple="" data-live-search="true" id="adminUserRoles" name="roles" title="Current Role(s)" data-value="post" tabindex="-98">
   <optgroup label="Group 2">
      <option name="User" value="User" data-value="Group 2">User</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Group 1">
       <option name="User" value="User" data-value="Group 1">User</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @mplungjan cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Comment: Please show HTML! We cannot guess the structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close.

Try the following,

```
    var roles = $("#adminUserRoles").find(':selected');

    $.each(roles , function (index, option) {

        var value = $(option).data("value");
    });
```

Comment: This did it, thank you. How is it that .data("value") gets my custom attribute though?

Comment: Not only that, it seems like you switched the .each function parameters. It should be  Function( index, element )

Comment: You can use data attribute to either get or set value. Please refer the following link,https://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```js
$("#but").on("click", function() {
  const vals = $("#adminUserRoles")
    .find("option:selected")
    .map(function() { return $(this).data("value")}).get();
  console.log(vals);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectpicker" multiple="" data-live-search="true" id="adminUserRoles" name="roles" title="Current Role(s)" data-value="post" tabindex="-98">
   <optgroup label="Group 2">
      <option name="User" value="User" data-value="Group 2">User</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Group 1">
       <option name="User" value="User" data-value="Group 1">User</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
<button type="button" id="but">Click</button>
```

Comment: how exactly does '.data("value") return the data-value attribute?

Answer (score 0):

This will also work..

```
var roles = $("#adminUserRoles option:selected").map(function(){return $(this).data("value");}).get();
console.log(roles);
```